# how to correct large size and creation of autoloader_classmap.php in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, autoload

There is a file in our Laravel 4 codebase,

```
/vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php
```

Which has over 7,000 entries?

Is this file compiled automatically?  This is not clear because I don't have access to any git history.

Is this a normal size?  My out-of the box laravel 4 install has about 15 entries; and I think that this should be taken care of by the mappings in the `composer.json` autoload.psr-4 locations.  I am hoping to reduce this size and handle this through native autoloading, thanks.

Comment: This is compiled automatically. You can re-generate it using `php artisan optimize`. The size seems fine.

Comment: Thank you - though the defined array seems huge to me, and `optimize` seems ironic :)  The values themselves have `$baseDir` as part of the path, and at 7K entries and with our root, that's like 250K alone!  Wouldn't it be more "optimal" to have general rules for locations and use folders/namespaces?